# Validate Useragent with Regex

Tags: regex, user-agent

I'm trying to validate a useragent which has the following format

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android <android>; <locale>; <device> Build/<build>) AppleWebKit/<webkit> (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/<safari>
```

The useragent could be i.e.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.2.2; en-us; AFTB Build/JDQ39) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
```

My regex so far is

```
Mozilla\/5\.0 \(Linux; U; Android (\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+); [a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2} (AFTA|AFTN|AFTS|AFTB|AFTT|AFTM|AFTKMST12|AFTRS) Build\/([A-Z0-9])\) AppleWebKit\/(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+) \(KHTML, like Gecko\) Version\/4\.0 Mobile Safari\/(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)
```

Test: https://regex101.com/r/nXKYBB/1

But it didn't match. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed a `;` after `en-de` and `+` after `[A-Z0-9]`:

```
Mozilla\/5\.0 \(Linux; U; Android (\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+); [a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}; (AFTA|AFTN|AFTS|AFTB|AFTT|AFTM|AFTKMST12|AFTRS) Build\/([A-Z0-9]+)\) AppleWebKit\/(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+) \(KHTML, like Gecko\) Version\/4\.0 Mobile Safari\/(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nXKYBB/3)

Note that it might be a good idea to match non-capturing groups, `(?:...)`, rather than capturing groups if you do not plan to use those captured subvalues later, and use `\s` to match whitespace.

Also, if you plan to match the whole string, wrap the pattern with `^` and `$`.