# How to validate the user agent is correct before making an http client request call?

Tags: c#, httpclient

I have a list of user agents that I use when creating http client requests.

Sometimes some of those user agents gives me an error:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", currentUserAgent);
HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync($"{pageUrl}");
```

I get an error like:

> The format of value 'Mozilla/5.0(iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X;
>   en-us)AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Version/4.0.4Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.10' is invalid

Is it possible to validate the user agent before hand?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following Regex expression to validation the user agent string before assignment:

`Mozilla\/5\.0 \(Linux; U; Android (\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+); [a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}; (AFTA|AFTN|AFTS|AFTB|AFTT|AFTM|AFTKMST12|AFTRS) Build\/([A-Z0-9]+)\) AppleWebKit\/(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+) \(KHTML, like Gecko\) Version\/4\.0 Mobile Safari\/(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)`

Please check the original answer: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51903023/13378146)